# Scheduled Task on Windows 2000 Server forcing a window to appear

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

**Problem**

I need to run a java jar file through a scheduled task on a Windows 2000 Server.  The scheduled task will call a batch file and the batch file will only contain

```
java -jar program.jar
```

The program that runs uses these three imports for emulating typing on a keyboard.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

The program has a step where it opens an external program for the program to type information into.  The problem I am facing is that when the batch file is run manually (I go in and double click the batch file) it runs the program fine, but when I use the scheduled task to run the batch file it does not open the external program.
I have tried to change the batch file to say

```
show "myWindow" java -jar program.jar
```

but that did not work when running with the scheduled task.

I believe that the scheduled task is running in the background and therefore it will not open the external program, so I am hoping that someone can help me to get the task to run in the foreground (have it open a window) or if there is another solution to this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't there a "interact with desktop" setting or similar ? Unfortunately I have no W2K within my reach ;-)

Comment: Do you have specified all application file names (java, the other application) with full paths and file extension in double quotes? A common problem on running something as scheduled task is depending on environment variables like __PATHEXT__ and __PATH__ and others which are usually different in scheduled task environment in comparison to user environment.

Comment: @Marged There is a security setting in which I have specified INTERACTIVE as a user (the other names here are Administrators, SYSTEM, Users). Adding the INTERACTIVE did not work even though it had full control.

Comment: @Mofi The program that runs has the file paths in the code directly.  I know that the program runs when the scheduled task executes, but it does not interact with the computer in the way it should. One of the first things the program should do is hit caps lock but that does even happen when it is run through the scheduled task.